# Windows 10 cannot access network shared locations or drives

Tags: windows-10

My shared drives were inaccessible after updating my windows 10 to the latest  “Windows 10 Fall Creators Update”.

Within the latest “Windows 10 Fall Creators Update” the Guest access in SMB2 is disabled by default.

You can change this setting within your group policy settings.

Right click the Windows Icon at the bottom left of the task bar, or select the windows key + r

Within the run box, type “gpedit.msc”

Within the local Group Policy Editor, select “Administrative Templates”

Select “Network”

Select ”Lanman Workstation”

Double click “Enable Insecure guest logons” option

Tick the “Enable” option

Select OK

If this did not work consider checking this registry key too:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters\AllowInsecureGuestAuth
```

It should be set to 1 for your case.

Note: By enabling insecure guest logons, this setting reduces the security of Windows clients.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4046019/guest-access-smb2-disabled-by-default-in-windows-10-server-2016

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Within the latest “Windows 10 Fall Creators Update” the Guest access in SMB2 is disabled by default.

You can change this setting within your group policy settings.

Right click the Windows Icon at the bottom left of the task bar, or select the windows key + r

Within the run box, type “gpedit.msc”

Within the local Group Policy Editor, select “Administrative Templates”

Select “Network”

Select ”Lanman Workstation”

Double click “Enable Insecure guest logons” option

Tick the “Enable” option

Select OK

If this did not work consider checking this registry key too:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters\AllowInsecureGuestAuth
```

It should be set to **1** for your case.
(Credits: zhqiat)

Note: By enabling insecure guest logons, this setting reduces the security of Windows clients. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4046019/guest-access-smb2-disabled-by-default-in-windows-10-server-2016

Comment: Finally found your answer, thank you :)

Comment: That last bit (registry check) did it for me - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One additional thing to look into.

If you apply the `gpedit.msc` solution as qore5 has mentioned and it still does not work, you may need to edit a separate registry key.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters`

and change `AllowInsecureGuestAuth` to 1.

This has happened after several Windows 10 updates.

Comment: Hope this gets more upvotes. For the time being I will include it in the accepted answer to be seen.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works by lowering the security on the client side.  It is not enforcing the restriction in Windows 10 / Windows Server which was added for security purposes. It requires adjusting each of your clients.

On the other hand, the real answer is to raise the security on the server side and remove any mapping to guest accounts

**ADD THESE LINES**

   `[global]
   client min protocol = SMB3
   client max protocol = SMB3
   restrict anonymous = 2
   encrypt passwords = true`

**REMOVE**

- the `map to guest` option (which I had as bad user)
- any 'guest ok' line in your smbd.conf

restart samba and you'll be prompted for a username/password instead.

Answer (score -1):

Simple>>

Unhide Files and Folder

Go to C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy

> 1st make a backup Machine & User folder and also gpt.ini

__then

> Delete items in Machine folder & User folder (*Do not delete Machine & User folder)

__go back

Delete gpedit.msc from C:\Windows\System32

Restart your computer

and then enjoy your life..